# Sencha Sass file compilation issue

Tags: sass, sencha-touch

I'm new to sencha and I'm trying to compile a sencha Sass file and I'm getting this error:

> Line 7 of _Button.scss : Undefined mixin 'toolbar-button'

In my CSS, I'm not using anything related to *toolbar-button*. Where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

*_Button.scss* is a style sheet from Sencha Touch default theme.

That's why I think you have a button in a toolbar in your application and Sencha Touch tries to apply the default style to it. However, it can't do it because you didn't include Sencha Touch default styles in your `.scss` file.

Try to add these lines at the top of your `.scss` style file:

```
@import 'sencha-touch/default';
@import 'sencha-touch/default/all';
@include sencha-buttons;
@include sencha-toolbar;
```